# Dart initializer list and access of recently filled instance variable

Tags: dart

I am trying to initialize some event stream in a class. I want that stream to be final, but controlled by `StreamController`. I have tried following code:

```dart
import "dart:async";

class Dog {
  final StreamController _onBarkController;
  final Stream onBark;

  Dog() :
    _onBarkController = new StreamController(),
    onBark = _onBarkController.stream;

}
```

But this code is illegal, because the access (even implicit) to `this` is forbidden in the initializer list.

Is there any way how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a great way to solve the general problem of needing to destructure some object into multiple final fields, which is basically what you're attempting here. But the good news is that usually you don't really need to. The two approaches I would recommend are factory constructors and not keeping derived state.

Factory constructors are great because you can perform arbitrary computation to create your arguments before calling the real constructor, which can usually only have an initializer list. In this case you can have a factory constructor create the StreamController and pass it and the stream to a private constructor.

Even better for you though, would be to not store the Stream in a field because you can get to it via the controller. I do this all the time with streams:

```dart
class Dog {
  final StreamController _onBarkController = new StreamController();
  Stream get onBark => _onBarkController.stream;
}
```

onBark is really a value derived from _onBarkController, so there's no need to store it.

Comment: Careful with non broadcast stream